# Apache Shiro - Subject Permissions and Target Allowances

Tags: authorization, shiro

Let's say we have multiple users and documents.

Users can have access to documents using permissions, such as: document:id:action (e.g. document:1:edit, document:2:read).

Now I also like to have the option to grant access to multiple users from my document-side, e.g. (user:*:read) -> all users should have read-access.

Am I missing something obvious in Apache Shiro or is this not possible?

`SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(document:8:read)` will only cover the direction user -> document.

How do I implement something like
`SecurityUtils.getTarget().allows(user:7:write)` ?

I can get all document-permissions as a List. How would I check against this list for a certain permission?

Essentially I'm looking for a helper-function on Shiro's side such that I can do:

`allPermissions = ['user:6:write', 'user:*:read']
permissionToCheck = 'user:95:read'
isPermitted(allPermissions, permissionToCheck)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose an answer myself:

```
List<String> notebookPermissions = ...;
String permissionToCheck = "user:read:" + getUser().getId();
Permission resolvedPermissionToCheck = resolver.resolvePermission("user:read:" + getUser().getId())
List<Permission> permissions = notebookPermissions.stream().map(p -> 
     resolver.resolvePermission(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
for (Permission perm : permissions) {
  if (perm.implies(resolvedPermissionToCheck)) {
     return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

What do you think about this approach?